# Java SE window saying "Not Responing". Do I have an issue with my try/catch?

Tags: java, 2d, try-catch

I am having an issues when trying to write a file. It is a level editor in a Tower defense game. Every time I click 'S' to save it freezes and the moment I click on the display screen it says not responding then I have to shut it down manually with task manager.

```
package helpers;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;

import data.Tile;
import data.TileGrid;

public class Leveler {

    public static void saveMap(String mapName, TileGrid grid) {
        String mapData = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.getTilesWide(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; i < grid.getTilesHigh(); j++) {
                mapData += getTileID(grid.GetTile(i, j));
            }
        }

        //Trying to save a game map to a text file
        try{
        File file = new File(mapName);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        bw.write(mapData);
        bw.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static String getTileID(Tile t) {
        String ID = "e";
        switch (t.getType()) {
        case Grass:
            ID = "0";
            break;
        case Dirt:
            ID = "1";
            break;
        case Water:
            ID = "2";
            break;
        case Stone:
            ID = "3";
            break;
        case NULL:
            ID = "4";
            break;
        }
        return ID;
    }
}
```

[Code by XXCODE_MAN94XX](http://pastebin.com/Qdcjz9fw).

Answer (score 2):

This line looks suspiciously like an Infinite Loop:

```
public static void saveMap(String mapName, TileGrid grid) {
        String mapData = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.getTilesWide(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; i < grid.getTilesHigh(); j++) {  <-- Don't you mean "j"?
                mapData += getTileID(grid.GetTile(i, j));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I skimmed over that for a while, but didn't notice it!